# Three JS - Retain objects depth from camera.layers(1) when rendering camera.layers(0)

Tags: three.js, depth-buffer

I'm creating a scene with a centre object and 6 cubes floating around it, I've also used a bloom post-processing effect across the whole scene, but now i've been tasked with modifying the code so that only the centre object has the bloom effect on it, with the cubes being rendered normally.

I came across the concept of using `camera.layers` and it seemed to work at first with the bloom only affecting the centre object, until I rotated around a little and realised that I've lost the depth of the centre object so the cubes now rotate in front of the centre object.

[Looks like this](https://ibb.co/b6yGuz)

Here's the solution that I found:

https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-effectcomposer-layers/3158/3

Here's my render loop:

```
this._renderer.clear();

this._sceneLights.directionalLight.layers.set(1);
this._sceneLights.ambientLight.layers.set(1);
this._camera.layers.set(1);
this._effectComposer.render();

this._renderer.clearDepth();

this._sceneLights.directionalLight.layers.set(0);
this._sceneLights.ambientLight.layers.set(0);
this._camera.layers.set(0);
this._renderer.render(this._scene, this._camera);
```

Also I have `this._renderer.autoClear = false;`

And `centreMesh.layers.set(1);`

I've come across a few options suggesting using 2 scenes but I don't know if the depth issue will still persist doing that? The `camera.layers` solution was so close to what I wanted as well

Is there a way to retain the depth of the centre object between layers?

P.S. I know that I'm clearing the depth buffer, but I have to otherwise the cubes aren't displayed/rendered, I'm just wondering if there's a way to retain the depth and possibly apply it again after the normal render?

Comment: Why not simply add a sprite with a radial gradient texture instead of the center sphere?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little? Why would that help? Would that make the centre object/sprite appear to have a bloom-like effect on it, without needing the effect composer?

Answer (score 0):

A sprite instead of a sphere:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(-3, 5, 8);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
light.position.setScalar(10);
scene.add(light);
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5));

var boxes = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  let box = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(2, 2, 2), new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: "maroon"
  }));
  boxes.push(box);
  scene.add(box);
}

var sunBlur = new THREE.Sprite(new THREE.SpriteMaterial({
  color: "yellow",
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/sprites/spark1.png')
}));
sunBlur.scale.set(10, 10, 1);
scene.add(sunBlur);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var time = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  time += clock.getDelta();
  boxes.forEach((b, idx) => {
    b.position.x = Math.cos(idx * (Math.PI / 3) + time) * 5;
    b.position.z = Math.sin(idx * (Math.PI / 3) + time) * 5;
  });
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Dude, I really appreciate the effort there man, your scene looks just like mine haha. I asked my line manager if this was a viable solution and he turned it down, didn't wanna use sprites (because our camera moves around the scene, sometimes the back of the sprite plane is visible, looks funky). So we've actually dropped the bloom effect completely, in favour of just using a `PointLight` at the centre, still would like a glow effect, just to get some colour bleed of the object, but he's happy with it, so meh. I'd say this is a definite alternative though, depending on use case, thanks man

Comment: @HazeyAce Maybe it's possible to do something wiht GodRays then? )

Comment: @HazeyAce I think you're looking for that :) https://codepen.io/abberg/pen/pbWkjg

Comment: you sir, are a very cheeky man, that looks sweet, I'll propose it to him on monday :)